# Error compiling cpp code with mosquitto library with g++

Tags: c++, g++, mosquitto

I am tring to compile a c++ code using mosquitto, and I downloaded the packets for the clients in the raspberry pi which I want to run there.

I downloaded using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

but I think the library is not indexed correctly as when I try to compile my code using the g++ compiler it gives me an erros as :

```
cannot find -lmosquitto
```

I am ussing the following command to compile:

```
g++ -o mosquito mosquito.cpp -lmosquitto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should install libmosquitto-dev that is for development

so you should do this

```
sudo apt-get install libmosquitto-dev
```